# akka-http validate path segment

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

How to validate akka-http path segment in `PathMatcher`?
I would like to reject request (not simply mark it as `Unmatched`).

What I would like to achieve is to return *400 Bad request* if `SegmentAsUserId` marks segment as invalid:

```scala
path(SegmentAsUserId) { implicit userId =>
  concat(
    get {
      handleGet()
    },
    post {
      handlePost()
    }
  )
}
```

The only way I found for now is to throw an exception in `PathMatcher1`:

```scala
object SegmentAsUserId extends PathMatcher1[String] {
  override def apply(path: Path): PathMatcher.Matching[Tuple1[String]] = path match {
    case Path.Segment(segment, tail) =>
      if (ObjectId.isValid(segment))
        Matched(tail, Tuple1(segment))
      else
        throw InvalidUserIdException(segment)
    case _                           => Unmatched
  }
}
```

And yet another ugly solution which thrown an exception:

```scala
case class FindByIdRequest(id: String) {
  require(ObjectId.isValid(id), "The id " + id + " is invalid")
}

path(Segment).as(FindByIdRequest) { implicit userId =>
  // ...
}
```

I know that it may be possible with directives (reject). But is there a mechanism for path matches?

**Update:**

[The solution I came up with.](https://gist.github.com/aaabramov/62f5eaadb82c366c48ac2cad7219fe3e)

Comment: You can create a directive that does it exactly. To extract the uri and create a response in the case of an error in the path or whatever or call the inner route. The directive can access to the RequestContext

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 that's what I wrote in the footer. But I am more interested in performing it in PathMatcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case it is not obvious from @TomerShetah answer that directives can be reused, you do something like:

```
object ValidatedObjectId {
  
  def apply(directive: Directive[String]): Directive[String] =
    directive.filter(
      id => ObjectId.isValid(id), // or just ObjectId.isValid
      rejectionObject // e.g. MalformedPathParamRejection("message")
    )
}


val complexRoute: Route = ValidatedObjectId(path(Segment)) { userId =>
  get {
    complete(StatusCodes.OK, s"userId is: $user")
  } ~
  post {
    user = userId
    complete(StatusCodes.OK)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for example. But complilation fails with `type mismatch;
 found   : akka.http.scaladsl.server.StandardRoute
 required: akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive[String]` for `reject`. Because `reject` returns a `Route`. Is there sort of `reject` as a `Directive`?

Comment: Solved with replacing `tflatMap` with `tfilter` which basically is designed for this. `def apply(directive: Directive[String]): Directive[String] =
      directive.tfilter(ObjectId.isValid, MalformedPathParamRejection("the name", "the error message"))`

Comment: The simplest way I've managed it to work: https://gist.github.com/aaabramov/62f5eaadb82c366c48ac2cad7219fe3e. Because example in the answer does not compile. If you would like to, you can update the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that `PathMatchers` is what you need for your use case. From Akka official [The PathMatcher DSL](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/path-matchers.html):

> The PathMatcher mini-DSL is used to match incoming URL’s and extract values from them. It is used in the path directive.

It is not used to check validity of those values. Therefore I don't think this is what you need.

There is a nice example there of how `PathMatcher` should be used:

```
val matcher: PathMatcher1[Option[Int]] =
  "foo" / "bar" / "X" ~ IntNumber.? / ("edit" | "create")

val route: Route =
  path(matcher) { i: Option[Int] =>
    complete(s"Matched X${i.getOrElse("")}")
  }
```

In order to achieve the check validations, please consider the following route:

```
var user = "none"

object ObjectId {
  def isValid(s: String): Boolean = s.startsWith("a")
}

val complexRoute: Route = path(Segment) { userId =>
  if (ObjectId.isValid(userId)) {
    get {
      complete(StatusCodes.OK, s"userId is: $user")
    } ~
    post {
      user = userId
      complete(StatusCodes.OK)
    }
  } else {
    complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest, s"userId $userId is not supported.")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But my reason to use `PathMatcher` is to be able to reuse this component across libraries. How to achieve this with directives?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov, Why can't you use my suggestion across libraries?

Comment: Directives can be reused